# The input is not prompting for the data. How do I address that?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm completing Python for Everyone on Coursera.  The following narrative is the the problem.  However, when I run the code in the grader tool, my output matches up with the desired output but an error message that reads "You must prompt for the data." pops up.  How do I need to change my code to address that error?

**Write a program to prompt the user for hours and rate per hour using input to compute gross pay. Pay should be the normal rate for hours up to 40 and time-and-a-half for the hourly rate for all hours worked above 40 hours. Put the logic to do the computation of pay in a function called computepay() and use the function to do the computation. The function should return a value. Use 45 hours and a rate of 10.50 per hour to test the program (the pay should be 498.75). You should use input to read a string and float() to convert the string to a number. Do not worry about error checking the user input unless you want to - you can assume the user types numbers properly. Do not name your variable sum or use the sum() function.**

```
#Input hours worked and pay rate
Hrs = input("Enter Hours:")
Pay = input("Enter Pay: ")

hrs = float(Hrs)
pay = float(Pay)

#Define the computepay function
def computepay():
    return hrs * pay

p = computepay()


#Consider overtime pay
if hrs <= 40 :
    print("Pay",p)
elif hrs > 41 :
    print("Pay", (40 * 10.5) + (hrs - 40) * (pay * 1.5))
else:
    print()
```

Comment: For me it looks fine but a nitpick I would like to say. What if the user enters 41 hours. Your code won't calculate it. make sure to do `elif hrs >= 41 :` instead of `elif hrs > 41 :` Also, a put a space in the end of `"Enter Hours:"` maybe that's causing the problem.

Comment: try removing whats inside of `input` method

Comment: @titusarmah99 I initially added a space, and then removed what's inside the input method (i.e. Hrs = input()
Pay = input() ); however, no luck.

Comment: @JosephAllenJr. find out if the input is single line or multi line. if it is single line, one input() is enough

Comment: https://medium.com/@mikismale/week-6-you-must-prompt-for-the-data-5f4a0615f29c

Comment: https://github.com/Lallo/PR4E/issues/3#issuecomment-618092780 <--- ask there

Comment: I got it.  Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the link below in comments, I have given the answer for the above question in that link

```
#Input hours worked and pay rate
Hrs = input("Enter Hours:")
Pay = input("Enter Pay: ")

hrs = float(Hrs)
pay = float(Pay)

#Define the computepay function
def computepay(hrs,pay):

    if hrs <= 40 :
        p=hrs*pay
    else:
        p=((40 * pay) + ((hrs - 40) * (pay * 1.5)))
    return p

d = computepay(hrs,pay)
print("Pay",d)
```

[image]